# Volume value label is not shown on vertical volume's value bar

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to create simple volume bar chart in trading view pine editor. but the today's market's value(it also called price line) of volume(last bar) is not shown in the right side bar ,normally as like as red market price label on price bar.
In its settings, in style tab, there is a switch for turning on price line, but it does not work too and only show the price's horizontal line, not its value label on side bar. After showing it, I also need to change its style and color based on some conditions.
I upload the sample image, I mean volume value label as like as red market price label in top window(candle stick chart)
I would appreciate if anyone can help me to solve it.

[image]

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © reza_najafi

//@version=4
//Main volume bar chart
study(title="IV", format=format.volume)
plot(volume, color= color.green,style=plot.style_columns, title="Volume bar's color")
hline(0, title='Zero line', color=color.gray, linestyle=hline.style_dashed, linewidth=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show the line with `trackprice=true`, but I'm not sure if you can add a label.

```
//@version=4
//Main volume bar chart
study(title="IV", format=format.volume)

plot(volume, color= color.green,style=plot.style_columns, title="Volume bar's color", trackprice=true)
hline(0, title='Zero line', color=color.gray, linestyle=hline.style_dashed, linewidth=1)
```

Comment: it shows only the horizontal line, it does not include price label

Comment: Exactly. That's what I said in my answer.

Comment: I found an answer plus your help by activating the price label in setting window of chart

Answer (score 0):

Could you use something like the below as an alternative.

```
offset_val = input(title="Label Offset", type=input.integer, defval=20)

va= volume
plot(va, color= color.green,style=plot.style_columns, title="Volume bar's color", trackprice=true)
hline(0, title='Zero line', color=color.gray, linestyle=hline.style_dashed, linewidth=1)
plotshape(va, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.blue,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="volume",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="volume")
```

But some how have an input for the plotshape title="volume" and use line.get_price function or another function to pull the volume the volume price into the label.